# Pandas how to calculate results based groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
date type  id
1215 click  1
1215 total  1
1215 total  2
1215 click  3
1215 total  3
...
```

If I perform the following operation:

```
df[['date','type','id']].groupby(['date','type']).agg('count')
```

I get this:

```
            id
date  type  
1215  click 221
      total 538
1216  click 264
      total 481
1217  click 231
      total 358
...
```

So basically, I can get how many people performed a click on a page, and the total number of visitors per day.

The next step that I want to do is to:

`Add up all the clicks and divide it by all the totals so that I can calculate the click rate.`

I am not sure how to perform this calculation based on the resulting dataframe.

What I want to calculate is this:

(221 + 264) / (538 + 481)

There are many rows in the resulting groupby df, so I prefer to do it programmatically.

Comment: please post your exact code, this is not syntactically correct

Comment: @e4c5 just fixed the code

Comment: Can you add more rows (3-4) to sample df and desired output drom sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, unstack the second-level index:

```
unstacked = df.groupby(['date','type']).agg('count').unstack()
#         id      
#type click total
#date            
#1215   221   538
```

Now, divide `click` by `total`:

```
unstacked['id','click'] / unstacked['id','total']
#date
#1215    0.4107806691449814
#dtype: float64
```

If you want the total ratio, add the values in both columns and then divide:

```
agg = unstacked.sum().unstack()
agg['click'] / agg['total']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution would give me the ratio per day (which is definitely one step closer to what I want). I'd like to add up all the clicks and totals ( all_clicks / all_totals) and just get one ratio for the entire period.

Comment: Added cumulative sum.